# Perl Module Excel::Writer::XLSX. issue

Tags: perl, cygwin

I'm trying to install "Excel::Writer::XLSX." module using Cygwin, however I'm getting this below issue when its running the make file.

Any help to fix it will be appreciated

Running make for J/JM/JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.88.tar.gz

```
dmake.exe:  Error executing '\bin\bash': No such file or directory
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'blib\lib\Excel\Writer\.exists'
  JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.88.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK

Failed during this command:
 JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.88.tar.gz      : make NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dmake` and `C:\Perl64` in your output are clues that you have some other version of Perl for Windows on your system, and it appears in your `PATH` ahead of your Perl for Cygwin. Fix that issue first.

Comment: Thanks @mob . I was fooling myself.  I never had perl in cygwin but was using activeperl. So I uninstall active perl and install cygwin perl and update the cygwin as well.         However , new beast appear any idea . Running make for J/JM/JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.88.tar.gz
Can't exec "make": No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.22/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2243.
  JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.88.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 JMCNAMARA/Excel-Writer-XLSX-0.88.tar.gz      : make NO

Comment: You need to install `make` on Cygwin. I think it's in a `make` package.